How to determine a safe range of addresses to read from physical memory for 16gb of RAM?
I'm using RWEverything to read physical memory. It works fine, but if I try to read an address that is too big then it results in a BSOD.
For example, 0x0000eef777340000
is going to BSOD me.
How to calculate the maximum safe address to read from by knowing only my physical RAM size?

You can ask Windows how much physical memory is available (see GlobalMemoryStatusEx() and GetPhysicallyInstalledSystemMemory()), and then don't exceed it.
Keep in mind that the PC hardware rand the OS reserve portions of RAM for their own use, so you will not be able to access all of the memory.
